# Google Sheets List and Category

Tags: google-sheets

I have two ranges. The first range has a list of dogs, and the second range has a list of cats.
I created a dropdown list contains all Dogs and Cats. How Can I change dynamical the category? (Orange colour on screenshot) If someone chose Dog, the category will change to "Dogs". Same with cats.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom formula for the dropdown:

```
=MATCH(B1, QUERY({C1:C8}, "select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.+)s")&"'"), 0)
```

Where `B1` is the cell that the dropdown is in, `A1` is the cell where the user chooses from `'Cats'` or `'Dogs'`, and `C1:C8` is the list of possible values that needs to be filtered.

The spreadsheet when the value entered matches:

[image: The spreadsheet with valid input]

The spreadsheet when the value entered doesn't match:

[image: The spreadsheet with invalid input]

If you want it as a dropdown list, you can filter the range of items and then reference that in the data validation:

```
=QUERY({C1:C8}, "select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.+)s")&"'")
```

[image: Spreadsheet with dropdown list]

Answer (score 0):

Try, if E6 for instance is the value choosen in the dropdown list

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(E6,"\w+")&"s"
```

[image]